SQL unique value one column but return entire row
In SQLite Browser v3.12.2 (using SQLite v3.35.5) I can use the SQL code below to return those records with unique values in just one column ColHead:
SELECT 
    ColHead, COUNT(*) AS ColHead_COUNT 
FROM
    DatabaseName
GROUP BY
    ColHead
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1

This successfully returns those unique value rows. However, it only returns that one column ColHead.
I need to find the unique values in just one column but the result set must include all the columns of each record.

You are not the first person to have this requirement.  Please edit your question and describe what you have found in your research and why those examples aren't working for you.

The easiest way to solve this is probably with NOT EXISTS, where you select those rows for which not exists another row with the same colhead.
In SQLite every row has a unique ID called ROWID that you can use to see whether you look at the same row or another.
SELECT *
FROM mytable my_row
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 'another row with the same colhead'
  FROM mytable other_row
  WHERE other_row.colhead = my_row.colhead
  AND other_row.rowid <> my_row.rowid
);

Another option is to modify your query slightly to get the ROWIDs (with MIN(rowid) or MAX(rowid)) for the single-row "groups" and use these to select the complete rows with an IN clause:
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE rowid IN
(
  SELECT MIN(rowid)
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY colhead
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
);

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/KWUApj9z

I have attempted both suggestions. The 1st one does not return results at all. The 2nd does not return ONLY unique values.
I tested the 2nd one more often. There are two collections of data in my database. I know there are many duplicates but I do not want those duplicates.
The result should be only those records which are unique in either one of those 2 collections as they are combined.
Thank you.

The two queries do exactly the same thing. If they show different results, you made a mistake. It is impossible for the queries to return two or more rows with the same colhead. If the queries return no rows, this means that there are no colheads in the table that only occur once. I have added a demo fiddle to my answer that shows that both queries work correctly.

I don't know what you mean by "There are two collections of data in my database". A database mainly consists of tables. So, do you mean two tables? Maybe you want to open a new request with a new question related to those two "collections". Show sample data and the (altered?) queries then along with the results you get and the results you want.
